# Copy and detach object with active bindings in R

Tags: r, binding

I have an object in `R` with active bindings (let's call it `model`). I want to make a copy (similar to this for static bindings `model_copy <- model`), and then make some changes to `model_copy` without affecting `model`.

Is there a way to copy such a `<Object containing active bindings>` and detach the binding?

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Are these bindings that you set up yourself? How did you set them up?

Comment: Yes, I am sorry and I am aware that a minimal example is the best way to go. Unfortunately, the package that I use (and which create these objects) are not that easy to install.